# Azure Web Jobs with Service Bus Topic Integration

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-webjobs, azure-servicebus-topics

I have created subscription(s) for some of the existing Azure Service Bus topic(s).

Now i need to create Azure Web Jobs that will process for any new Message arriving at the Topic end. This whole process will be used as part of incremental load.

Please provide some input/reference for implementing the above work flow.

Thanks! in advance

Comment: You could have a look at [Using triggers & binding in Azure Functions](https://www.rickvandenbosch.net/blog/using-triggers-bindings-in-azure-functions-v2/). The implementation should be fairly simple.

Comment: I have a service bus connection from a different Azure subscription. Now from my current subscription (which is Dev instance) can i set up a trigger & binding with Azure function. My requirement is simple just read the message from the topic and generate a json file,persist it to ADLS.

Answer (score 0):

You can have Azure Functions instead of Web Jobs to process the messages, which comes with ServiceBusTrigger. You could also go for Web Jobs to process the messages. Refer the following links for more details

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Processing-Service-Bus-84db27b4
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/31981.azure-webjobs-servicebustrigger.aspx

You should provide the Topic Subscription path in place of Queue path to receive message from Subscriptions.